# Multi Delete not working

Tags: mysql

I have a 9 table db set up like this.

TableA
acct_id

TableB
tabB_id
tabA_id_fk

TableC
tabC_id
tabB_id_fk

TableD
tabD_id
tabB_id_fk

TableE
tabE_id
tabB_id_fk

I'm sure you see the pattern by now. The second table reference the first and all others reference the second. The second table (TableB) has seven tables which reference it through foreign keys. One of the tables is one-to-many with TableB, let's say TableD. I want to delete the corresponding rows in all the tables with one query. I've searched for awhile and can't find an answer. Here is the SQL statement I'm using.

```
DELETE FROM photos, location, contacts, messages, stats, viewed_by, ethnicity,  profile, members
USING photos INNER JOIN location 
INNER JOIN contacts 
INNER JOIN messages 
INNER JOIN stats 
INNER JOIN viewed_by 
INNER JOIN ethnicity 
INNER JOIN profile 
INNER JOIN members 
WHERE photos.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND location.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND stats.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND viewed_by.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND ethnicity.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND profile.member_id_fk = members.member_id 
AND members.member_id=?
```

The query does not return any errors but it also doesn't delete any rows. What could be the problem?

Should I just use nine seperate delete queries, one for each table?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I would recommend you start formatting your SQL.  Makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Sorry. I just started using this site. I'll get around to learning the interface when I finish my project.

Comment: I was talking about in your project.  I assume you copy/pasted your query from there?  Have easy to read SQL in your project will save you a lot of headaches.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first answer assumes InnoDB. This answer does this for MyISAM.
[delete in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)

```
> desc parent; desc child_1; desc child_2;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| parent_id_fk | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| parent_id_fk | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

> select * from parent; select * from child_1; select * from child_2;
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Andreas    |
|  2 | Wederbrand |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | parent_id_fk | name      |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |            1 | Child 1 1 |
|  2 |            1 | Child 1 2 |
|  3 |            2 | Child 2 1 |
|  4 |            2 | Child 2 2 |
+----+--------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | parent_id_fk | name      |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |            1 | Child 1 1 |
|  2 |            1 | Child 1 2 |
|  3 |            2 | Child 2 1 |
|  4 |            2 | Child 2 2 |
+----+--------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

> delete p, c1, c2 from parent p, child_1 c1, child_2 c2 where p.id = c1.parent_id_fk and p.id = c2.parent_id_fk and p.id = 2;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.33 sec)
```

Your query could be correct, I don't have your tables, but test with

```
DELETE photos, location, contacts, messages, stats, viewed_by, ethnicity,  profile, members
FROM photos 
INNER JOIN location 
INNER JOIN contacts 
INNER JOIN messages 
INNER JOIN stats 
INNER JOIN viewed_by 
INNER JOIN ethnicity 
INNER JOIN profile 
INNER JOIN members 
WHERE photos.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND location.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND stats.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND viewed_by.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND ethnicity.profile_id_fk = profile.profile_id 
AND profile.member_id_fk = members.member_id 
AND members.member_id=?
```

Comment: Thank Andreas but that gives me the same result - no errors and nothing changed. I'm thinking just use 9 separate queries since I don't expect users to be constantly deleting accounts. The overhead on the db should be minimal because they are all single rows accept for the photos. I'll follow your advice and use the InnoDB tables from now on. Sounds like the way to go. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you do a select that shows all the data that should be deleted you should be able to replace `select * from` with `delete <list of tables> from`. Try to do your query as a select and see if you get any results.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your foreign keys with `on delete cascade`, that makes all tables that reference a foreign key delete it's values.

Read about [foreign keys constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) especially this part

> InnoDB rejects any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create
>   a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
>   candidate key value in the parent table. When an UPDATE or DELETE
>   operation affects a key value in the parent table that has matching
>   rows in the child table, the result depends on the referential action
>   specified using ON UPDATE and ON DELETE subclauses of the FOREIGN KEY
>   clause. InnoDB supports five options regarding the action to be taken.
>   If ON DELETE or ON UPDATE are not specified, the default action is
>   RESTRICT.
>
> ```
> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.
> ```
>
> Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between
>   two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act
>   on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.
>       Note
>
> ```
> Currently, cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.
> ```

Comment: That's great except I'm using MyISAM.

Comment: So no real foreign keys, just "soft" keys. I always suggest to people to move to InnoDB. It's the default engine since mysql 5.5, it's faster on most operations, it has better locking mechanisms and real foreign keys. I'll try to create a myisam cascade delete for you.

Comment: Thank Andreas but that gives me the same result - no errors and nothing changed. I'm thinking just use 9 separate queries since I don't expect users to be constantly deleting accounts. The overhead on the db should be minimal because they are all single rows accept for the photos.

Comment: I'll follow your advice and use the InnoDB tables from now on. Sounds like the way to go.